# How to set imageview height to match image ratio in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list of Imageviews that have their width set by the weight of a linear layout. How can I set the height of the Imageviews to ensure that they keep the original aspect ratio of the bitmaps being loaded into the image.

Here is a portion of my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll_auction"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/auction_image_height"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/image_view_background_unselected"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/niv_auctionImage1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute called `scaletype` to the imagevie and set it to `fitxy`

Sample

`android:scaleType="fitXY"`

It will auto scale your image base on the wieght you specify in your attribute

Comment: I was under the impression that fitXY would stretch the picture the fill the ImageView, and thus not maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: Instead doing it in xml. Do it programatically

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifying a width through the layout weight, AND you want the picture the keep its aspect ratio, you need the height to then be wrap_content. Adjust view bounds is also correct, and I would use the scaleType fitCenter.

You also want to make sure you set the image to be scaled as the src, not as the background, which will always be stretched.

Give this a go.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll_auction"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="30"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/image_view_background_unselected"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:src="@drawable/example_image"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/niv_auctionImage1" />
```